# CSS - Change State of 2 elements on hover

Tags: css, hover

```
<li class="red">
<p><a href="#">Home</a></p>
</li>
```

In the CSS, I'd like the bg color of the li element to change, BUT the color of the text has to change too. The problem is, even after I hover of ther li element, I have to go further and actually touch the text in order for it's color to change.

I'll be amazed if this can work.

Answer (score 0):

First remove `<p>` tag

```
li.red > a:hover {  
    color: red;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li:hover {
   background-color: blue;
}

li:hover p,
li:hover a {
   color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are **2** things you should take into account:

1. `<p></p>` is a block level element. It is not used inside inline-element, in this case, `<li></li>`
2. Simply make your `<a></a>` tag to be a block level element.

So your code should be like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="red">
       <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then you could come up with the CSS like this:

```
.red a:hover {
   padding: 10px 20px;
   display: block;
   background-color: #9900;
   color: #FFFFFF;
}
```